# How do I remove points to subtract the $b$ term in a linear regression fit?

Tags: linear-regression

I have a scatterplot of points with a fit of $y = mx + b$.
I would like to only keep the points such that the linear fit would be:
$y = mx$.

How do I subtract out the points contributing to the $b$ term in the linear regression fit?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Are you asking for refitting a model $y=\beta x$, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to refit the model to = by subtracting. I have two images: red and green. I would like to correct for bleed-through of green into the red color channel. I assume the red image is = "Red"+"Green" and I would like to subtract the contribution of points in the  term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OLS estimator of the intercept is 
$$
\hat{b} = \bar{Y}_n - \hat{m}\bar{X}_n,
$$
hence, if there is a non-zero correlation between $Y$ and $X$, then the easiest way is to insure that both $\bar{Y}_n$ and $\bar{X}_n$ are zero. E.g., you can subtract the sample mean from $Y$ and $X$ in order to get $b=0$.